# How to cast a shared_ptr<vector<derived class>> to a shared_ptr<vector<base class>>>?

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, stdvector

As the title,I have a odd requirement.
Code examples:

```
class Base{
}
class Derived: Base{
}

//I want cast that.
shared_ptr<vector<Derived*>>  ->   shared_ptr<vector<Base*>>
```

Here is my way:

```
shared_ptr<vector<Derived*>> derived_vector_sp;

auto* base_vector_rawptr = (vector<Base*> *)derived_vector_sp.get();

shared_ptr<vector<Base*>> base_vector_sp = make_shared<<vector<Base*>>>(*base_vector_rawptr);
```

It works.But in this way I create anthor vector.And two shared_ptr manage two different vecotr.

**So is there any way finish this case directly**?such as:

```
//this way doesn't work.
shared_ptr<vector<Base*>> base_vector_sp = static_pointer_cast<vector<Base*>>(derived_vector_sp);
```

Comment: You can't. Treating a vector of `Dog*` as if it was a vector of `Animal*` would mean you could add a `Cat*` to it.

Comment: You cannot cast `vector<ptr*>` from one `ptr` type to another. Not supported.

Comment: Sounds like an XY-Problem. You should explain why you need that, there is likely a better/different solution for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast `shared_ptr<vector<Derived*>>` to `shared_ptr<vector<Base*>>`  because `vector<Derived*>` and `vector<Base*>`  are two distinct types that are not related to each other.

That `Derived` and `Base` are related to each other does not matter in that case. The type you create with `std::vector<Derived*>` and `std::vector<Base*>` are created from the class templated `std::vector`, so it is only the inheritance given by the `std::vector` class template that is relevant here.

> But in this way I create another vector. And two `shared_ptr` manage two different vecotr.

You could think about creating a `view` on your original `vector<Derived*>` container.

Comment: 'You could think about creating a view on your original vector<Derived*> container.'I don't understand that.What does “a view” mean？

Comment: @Jevon54 Create a class that can hold `std::vector<Derived*>` but the iterator and the access will return a pointer to `Base`. But as I said in the other comment it sounds like an XY Problem. So you should explain in your question why you need that. What problem you try to solve with that.

Answer (score 1):

A *cast* is not possible, because even though `Derived` inherits `Base`, the classes `vector<Derived*>` and `vector<Base*>` are completely separate classes with no relationship at all.

If you want a `vector<Base*>` from a `vector<Derived*>`, it is possible but you need to convert the pointers yourself. And you get a separate vector of course.

```
std::vector<Derived*> source;

// Don't use this, use the version below
auto result = std::vector<Base*>(source.size());
for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx < source.size(); ++idx) {
    result[idx] = source[idx];
}
return result;
```

Or in more idiomatic C++, we would simply let the constructor do the job:

```
auto result = std::vector<Base*>(begin(source), end(source));
```

**Random sidenote:**

- The cast:

  ```
  (vector<Base*> *)derived_vector_sp.get(); // don't do this!
  ```

  This is completely illegal. There is no `vector<Base*>` at that location, so
  attempting to use one is undefined behavior. It might look like it works, then you
  upgrade your compiler and it crashes.
- Using a `shared_ptr` in general is a code smell. It has a few good use cases, but most of the time you should be using the objects directly, or `unique_ptr`.
- Especially when we talk about a `std::vector` which is already itself a set of pointers.